# Penetration of Light through Fog

Tags: optics, visible-light, waves, scattering

Some kinds of light are able to penetrate through dense fog while some aren't. What is the cause of this difference?

How can this be formulated mathematically?

Edit: For example, there are special 'fog lights'. What differentiates them from regular light sources?

Comment: What 'kinds of light' are able to penetrate through dense fog, IYO?

Comment: Since there are separate 'fog lights', I was wondering what might differentiate them from regular light sources. Forgive me for my inadequate knowledge.

Comment: Mainly *marketing*, IMHO!

Comment: Concerning car "fog lights". I thought that auto companies were originally claiming that the yellow color of the lights was more effective at penetrating fog, but I think that that claim was debunked. I think that it was found that the low position of the fog lights and how the lights were angled did offer some small, marginal improvement over the main headlights for fog conditions, though. Like Gert said, I think it's mostly marketing.

Comment: foglamps are traditionally yellow because in the first cars, the headlights were kerosene lamps and their glass housings became yellowed with combustion products over time. Later, when electric lights were first put on cars, their lenses were tinted yellow to make their output resemble that of the kerosene lamps.

Answer (score 1):

Fog lights work not so much by using an optimal wavelength of light but rather by how the beam is focused. Fog lights are mounted low and have a beam that is aimed low and wide.

See this [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-fog-lights-work) on Quora.